# WSO2 passing a value from request

Tags: wso2

I'm new in WS02 but I'm having a trouble to get a url param and pass it.
Following the [Sending a Simple Message example](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Sending+a+Simple+Message)

my resource is

```
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/wholesales/{dlrcode}">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="message" value="Whole sales request"/>
                <property expression="/default/expression" name="p_dlrCode"/>
            </log>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="WholeSales"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
```

and my END is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="WholeSales" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <http method="get" uri-template="http://xxx/RDRSvc//vehicle/wholesaleD/{url.var.dlrcode}?format=json"/>
</endpoint>
```

but stil when I call api like

http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8280/rdr/wholesales/42103

I see no dlrCode ???

TID[-1234] [ESB] [2017-03-07 11:08:29,464] INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - message = "Whole sales request", p_dlrCode =

how can I put the 42103 in property p_dlrCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Your resource:

```
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/wholesales/{dlrcode}">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="message" value="Whole sales request"/>
                <property expression="get-property('uri.var.dlrcode')" name="p_dlrCode"/>
            </log>
            <send>
                <endpoint key="WholeSales"/>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
```

Your endpoint fixed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="WholeSales" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <http method="get" uri-template="http://xxx/RDRSvc//vehicle/wholesaleD/{uri.var.dlrcode}?format=json"/>
</endpoint>
```

Comment: Hi Jorge , thanks for quick response ... It work almost :) , property get value BUT still end point did get it ...Do I need to change something in END point declaration .. I don't see any difference in your responce ,...help

Comment: in your endpoint definition you use url.var.dlrcode, I update it with uri.var.dlrcode...it´s uri not url